# If the reduced homology of K is nonzero, k is evasive.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Where can I find a proof for this theorem of Kahn, Saks and Sturtevant? K is a simplicial complex.

> **Theorem** $\textbf{10.1}.$ If $\tilde H_*(K)\neq 0$, where $\tilde H_*(K)$ denotes the reduced homology of $K$, then $K$ is evasive.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this "evasiveness" property before, but a quick googling turns up e.g. [these notes](http://math.rice.edu/~forman/revisedevade.ps) which mention in the introduction that any non-evasive complex is contractible. Since K-theory is invariant under homotopy equivalences, a contractible space has the K-theory of a point. Similarly, any complex whose homology or cohomology or homotopy groups or... differs from that of a point is evasive.

The only paper of Kahn, Saks, and Sturtevant that I can find is a 1984 paper called *A topological approach to evasiveness* which may or may not mention this fact in passing (Springer is hiding it behind a paywall for me) but I would expect this property is so elementary as to not need a citation.